# Good Design for if else object mapping

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have this logic:

```
public void method(Boo result, Foo foo, Bar bar) {
   if(foo != null) {
      if(foo.getId() != null){
         result.setId(foo.getId());
      } else {
         result.setId(bar.getId());
      }
      if(foo.getName() != null){
         boo.setName(foo.getName());
      } else {
         result.setName(bar.getName());
      }
      // and many similar attributes
   } else {
      result.setId(bar.getId());
      result.setName(bar.getName());
      // and many similar attributes
   }
}
```

I find this way ugly, is there any way to make it in better design. I know that is better to use mapstruct, but in this project I can't.

Comment: Using the ternary operator would turn each if/else into a single line. Whether that's less ugly/more readable/better for your purposes, though, is an entirely different matter.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper I have a long attributes, If I use ternary operator, it can be ugly too

Comment: If you can modify the objects returning all these nullable fields, you could use [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html). It does not help much if you only wrap things locally here in your  `method`, though.

Comment: If you use [kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/), you can use [safe calls](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) with [elvis operators](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator), and the checks could be simplified to one line.

Comment: @Marc Please read the [guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/52915) and note how the current code will not be accepted on Code Review for being hypothetical.

Comment: @Hulk it was a typo, I fix it, thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With common class/interface:**

If `Foo` and `Bar` extend a common base class/interface you could create a generic method to apply the logic to any attribute.

For example lets say that they implement this interface:

```
public interface IBaseInterface {
    Long getId();
    String getName();
}
```

Then we could create this generic method:

```
public static <T> T getAttribute(IBaseInterface foo, IBaseInterface bar, Function<IBaseInterface, T> function) {
    if(foo != null) {
        T attribute = function.apply(foo);
        if(attribute != null) {
            return attribute;
        }
    }
    return function.apply(bar);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
result.setId(getAttribute(foo, bar, IBaseInterface::getId));
result.setName(getAttribute(foo, bar, IBaseInterface::getName));
```

**Without common class/interface:**

If they don't extend a common base class/interface you could still use this technique but you'd have to pass another parameter to the method:

```
public static <T> T getAttribute(Foo foo, Bar bar, Function<Foo, T> functionFoo, Function<Bar, T> functionBar) {
    if(foo != null) {
        T attribute = functionFoo.apply(foo);
        if(attribute != null) {
            return attribute;
        }
    }
    return functionBar.apply(bar);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
result.setId(getAttribute(foo, bar, Foo::getId, Bar::getId));
result.setName(getAttribute(foo, bar, Foo::getName, Bar::getName));
```

Comment: Both answers are very good, thank you for your response, I will wait a little if there are no better solution, I will accept one of them

Answer (score 2):

I'd switch the tests around.  It's a little cleaner, but it's still going to look messy.

```
public void method(Boo result, Foo foo, Bar bar) {
    setResult(result, bar);
    if (foo != null) { setResult(result, foo); }
}

private void setResult(Boo result, Bar bar) {
    result.setId(bar.getId());
    ...
}

private void setResult(Boo result, Foo foo) {
    if (foo.getId != null) { result.setId(foo.getId()); }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I agree with the last sentence *but it's still going to look messy* :)

Answer (score 1):

I avoid the if else using [`ObjectUtils::firstNonNull`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#firstNonNull-T...-) as bellow:

```
public void method(Boo result, Foo foo, Bar bar) {
   if(foo != null) {
      result.setId(ObjectUtils.firstNonNull(foo.getId(), bar.getId()));
      result.setId(ObjectUtils.firstNonNull(foo.getName(), bar.getName()));
      // and many similar attributes
   } else {
      result.setId(bar.getId());
      result.setName(bar.getName());
      // and many similar attributes
   }
}
```

---

**I'm open for other suggests!**

Answer (score 1):

By having `foo` as an `Optional` you could simplify your code like this:

```
Optional<Foo> optionalFoo = Optional.ofNullable(foo);
    
result.setId(optionalFoo.map(Foo::getId).orElseGet(bar::getId));
result.setName(optionalFoo.map(Foo::getName).orElseGet(bar::getName));
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`if` statements don't need curly brackets `{}` when there there is a single statement afterwards. Think of it as `{...}` as a single statement wrapping many other inside it.

Also Java doesn't really care about whitespaces and indentation so you can put multiple statements in the same line.

With this knowledge you can make the code prettier like this:

```
public void method(Boo result, Foo foo, Bar bar) {
    if (foo != null) {
        if (foo.getId() != null) result.setId(foo.getId());
        else result.setId(bar.getId());

        if (foo.getName() != null) boo.setName(foo.getName());
        else result.setName(bar.getName());

    } else {
        result.setId(bar.getId());
        result.setName(bar.getName());
   }
}
```

or at the very least remove the `{}`:

```
public void method(Boo result, Foo foo, Bar bar) {
    if (foo != null) {
        if (foo.getId() != null)
            result.setId(foo.getId());
        else 
            result.setId(bar.getId());

        if (foo.getName() != null)
            boo.setName(foo.getName());
        else 
            esult.setName(bar.getName());

    } else {
        result.setId(bar.getId());
        result.setName(bar.getName());
   }
}
```

Comment: Proble is not with long or short

Answer (score 0):

If the mapping objects are having same properties, and if you have spring beans in your project dependency, BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, destination);